# Are XML files in the classpath of a java application always loaded in memory?

Tags: java, xml, classpath

I have some configuration XML files in the classpath of a library project. Are these XML files always in main memory when the application ist running?

Additional Question: If not, how can i keep an XML file always in main memory?

Answer (score 2):

No file in classpath is loaded automatically, even class files need a reason to be loaded. You have to use [getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to access XML files. Then, it is unlikely you want to keep them in memory as byte or character arrays - better to convert them in more usable format.

If your application is executed under control of some web-container or application server, use its facilities to read configuration files.

Comment: I am loading the data from the xml files via getResource and parsing them into objects. I might need to do this very often since I need to instanciate some of the objects often. Maybe I should think of keeping the objects in some sort of Map to prevent a new instanciation.

Answer (score -1):

Generally configuration files are read when an application is starting. And then memory is flushed after reading those and application execution is started. But if you have to permanently keep those files in memory, You may use some sort of data structure to store your file contents. And give global and public access to these datastructes, to utilize them throughout your application.

Comment: A completely misleading explanation. There is no such thing in Java like "automagically reading config files before application start". All reading of config files is explicitly done in code, and its up to the programmer to keep things in memory or not.